# Efficient way to get all articles with a set of tags in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-match-all, relational-division

I need an efficient way to select all articles with at least tags "Tag1" and "Tag2".
This is the standart way with the following database schema:

```
articles(id, title)
article_tag(articleid, tagid)
tag(id, name)

SELECT a.*
FROM   article a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT   at.articleid
               FROM     article_tag at
                        INNER JOIN article a
                          ON a.id = at.articleid
                        INNER JOIN tag t
                          ON t.id = at.tagid
               WHERE    t.name IN ("Tag1","Tag2")
               GROUP BY at.articleid
               HAVING   Count(at.articleid) = 2) aa
     ON a.id = aa.articleid
```

Is there a more efficient way performance wise?

Comment: Do you have any limit on maximum number of tags?

Comment: No, there is no max limit, but minimum is two tags

Comment: You can remove join with article table in the subquery.

Comment: I added the `sql-match-all` tag.  This exact type of problem has been answered many times on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect this query to be faster (tailored to your conditions):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM  (
    SELECT at.articleid AS id
    FROM   article_tag at
    JOIN   tag t ON t.id = at.tagid
    WHERE  t.name = 'Tag1'
    ) a1
JOIN  (
    SELECT at.articleid AS id
    FROM   article_tag at
    JOIN   tag t ON t.id = at.tagid
    WHERE  t.name = 'Tag2'
    ) a2 USING (id)
JOIN article a USING (id);
```

However, the **most important** part here are **indexes**. The primary keys will be indexed automatically (I assume):

- articles on (id)
- article_tag on (articleid, tagid)  -- multi-column index
- tag on (id)

In addition these will help your case:

- tag on (name)
- article_tag on (tagid)

This is a special case of **relational division**. Here is an [extensive coverage of your case exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774879/939860). You will be surprised about how many good ways there are.